# OpenIddict: How to manually check access token and get identity

Tags: c#, openiddict

*I am using [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for authentication/authorization.*
I need to manually check access token and get user (ClaimsPrincipal) behind that token. How?

**Use case:**
I am using SignalR. On every method call from client I would like to check if user is authenticated. My plan is to send access token from Angular and check it in Hub method.  Basically same thing must happened when I use `[Authorize]` attribute on Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this question is related to [How to authorize SignalR Core Hub method with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765756/how-to-authorize-signalr-core-hub-method-with-jwt), I wouldn't recommend decrypting the opaque access tokens issued by OpenIddict yourself.

If you really want to do it yourself, you can manually instantiate a `TicketDataFormat` instance with the ASP.NET Core Data Protection "purpose strings" used by OpenIddict:

```
// Resolve the data protection provider from the DI container.
// Depending on where this snippet is used, you must be able
// to directly use constructor injection (e.g in a controller).
var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();

var protector = provider.CreateProtector(
    nameof(OpenIdConnectServerHandler),
    nameof(OpenIdConnectServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat),
    OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var format = new TicketDataFormat(protector);

// If the access token is not malformed, a non-null value
// is returned. Note that you'll have to manually validate
// the expiration date and the audience of the ticket.
var ticket = format.Unprotect("your access token");
```

Comment: Could you please provide update for openiddict version 3? Current implementation works for version 2 only

Comment: For openiddict v3: OpenIddictValidationService should be used
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1458#issuecomment-1150346790